# Python 3: Subclassing the threading class?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, inheritance

I am trying to subclass the threading class to spawn a thread when calling a URL and getting a response with below code:

```
import urllib
import threading

from urllib.request import urlopen

class DocConnection(threading.Thread):
    def _init_(self,query, timeout):
        self.query = query
        self.timeout = timeout
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        try:
            data = urllib.urlencode({'docQuery': self.query})
            request = urllib.request.Request('/my/url', data)
            http_file = urlopen(request, timeout=self.timeout)
            self.result = http_file.read()
            return
        except (urllib.HTTPError) as e:
            err = 'HTTP Error'
        except (urllib.URLError) as e:
            err = 'URL Error'

        print(err)
        #sublime.error_message(err)
        return False

e = DocConnection("peprika",12)
e.start()
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/peprika/PycharmProjects/DocSublimePlugin/Documentation.py", line 28, in <module>
    e = DocConnection("peprika",12)
  File "C:\Users\peprika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\threading.py", line 778, in __init__
    **assert group is None, "group argument must be None for now"
AssertionError: group argument must be None for now**
```

Can someone help me understand the issue ?

Comment: You've misspelled `__init__` as `_init_` (with one set of underscores rather than two) in your class.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the init function. It's `__init__` not `_init_`. In this case, when you instantiate your inherited class with those 2 attributes, it will call the Thread constructor with those attributes. And one of them is `group` that should be None according to the doc.